How to import functions from another file in Rust?
I have the following Rust project:
./
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── Easy
│   │   ├── 001_Two_Sum.rs
│   │   ├── 083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List.rs
│   │   └── bin
│   ├── lib.rs
│   └── utils
│       ├── list_node
│       │   └── mod.rs
│       └── mod.rs
└── target

src/lib.rs
pub mod utils;
pub use crate::utils::list_node::ListNode;

src/utils/mod.rs
pub mod list_node;

src/utils/list_node/mod.rs
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

impl ListNode {
  #[inline]
  pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    ListNode {
      next: None,
      val
    }
  }
}

src/Easy/083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List.rs
struct Solution;

use crate::utils::list_node::ListNode;


impl Solution {
    pub fn delete_duplicates(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        let n = ListNode::new(1);       
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("\nJob done!");
}


Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "leetcode"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
cargo-watch = "8.5.2"

[[bin]]
name = "001_Two_Sum"
path = "src/Easy/001_Two_Sum.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List"
path = "src/Easy/083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List.rs"

I'm trying to use ListNode struct in 083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List.rs file but I'm getting this error message:
failed to resolve: unresolved import
unresolved importrustc (Click for full compiler diagnostic)
083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List.rs(3, 12): a similar path exists: `leetcode::utils`

If I use: use crate::leetcode::utils::list_node::ListNode;
I get this another error message:
failed to resolve: could not find `leetcode` in the crate root
could not find `leetcode` in the crate rootrustc (Click for full compiler diagnostic)

Previously I tried other configurations (found on Internet and suggested by IAs) but nothing seems to work.
I'm working on EndeveaourOS distro with VSCode. Any suggestion?

Edit 1:
Thanks to Carson's answer that error message was removed but I'm getting a new error when running the program:
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `leetcode`?
 --> 021_Merge_Two_Sorted_Lists.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use leetcode::utils::list_node::ListNode;
  |     ^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `leetcode`?
  |
  = help: consider adding `extern crate leetcode` to use the `leetcode` crate

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.

I tried adding this line extern crate leetcode on program being run but I got this error:
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `leetcode`
 --> 021_Merge_Two_Sorted_Lists.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate leetcode;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.


Edit 2:
The error message described in Edit 1 was caused by configuration of Code Runner extension. I changed this:
"rust": "cd $dir && rustc --out-dir bin $fileName && $dir/bin/$fileNameWithoutExt",

to this:
"rust": "cd $dir && cargo run --bin $fileNameWithoutExt --quiet",

Alternatively, I could use SHIFT+CTRL+B to run the local configuration defined in .vscode/tasks.json.

Change use crate::utils::... to use leetcode::utils::....
With your split lib, [[bin]] setup, you are defining three crates:

leetcode as defined in lib.rs
001_Two_Sum
083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List

When you use crate:: inside 001_Two_Sum, crate refers to 001_Two_Sum, not leetcode.

The error message displayed on editor was removed with your suggestion, and ListNode struct is recognized and can be used and traced back, however when running the code I'm getting a new error, see my post.

I created a setup that matched your post, and I'm afraid I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. Using the crates direct name as the import path is working in every scenario I can set up(the package is named leetcode, and the bin has been added to the cargo.toml.

can you share your setup or project? can you publish on github please?

@ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα Just literally what's in your post. Works for me, too.

I've published my project so you can check it.

That has other issues like "this function takes 1 argument but 0 arguments were supplied" and "Option<Box<ListNode>> doesn't implement std::fmt::Display", not the ones you claim.

021_Merge_Two_Sorted_Lists.rs file is a finished code, I was replacing with a imported function. See that file please

083_Remove_Duplicates_from_Sorted_List.rs file is a code in progress

021 prints "([1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4]):  […] Job Done!"

Really? I'm getting an error showed in my OP

Yes, really, start from scratch, create what's in your post. Adjust according to this answer, then it works. Or similarly git clone <your repo>; cargo run --bin 21…

I will do that. Thanks.

I've created a new project with a the 021....rs file and utils dir, and I'm getting that damn error, BUT if I open my project with RustRover editor it runs OK, the same if I run directly it on terminal. It seems it is a problem with VSCode configuration or RunCode extension, I'll check it.
